# How to get "inner" buffer from closed multiline?

Tags: qgis-2.18

I have a vector layer containing a closed boundary multiline, and I'd like to extract a certain buffer which would exclude the part that fall outside of the closed boundary.

How would I accomplish this? 
I'm using QGIS 2.18.19.

Comment: Welcome to the GIS SE, please take the tour located here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour it will assist in helping you understand how the SE works. With regards to your question, could you add some images to the question explaining exactly what you are looking to do? From the text it is difficult to "see" exactly what you are trying to do. The clearer the question, the better answers you will get.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the tour. Useful indeed as it's my firts time here. And this is all taken care of.

Comment: Cool we all started here at some point. If you have questions post them...follow the rules and you will get answers...if you get an answer, just click the green box to show that you are happy and your problem is solved. It may help someone later on, down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

off the top of my head:

1) convert to polygon and buffer using negative distance (same as the width you want the buffer to be)

2) compute difference between oroginal polygon and buffered polygon.

Comment: Cool this made the trick. Never knew about negative buffers before that's why I got stuck. Thank you!